# How does the riemann tensor symplify to normal components in the second variation formula?

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, smooth-manifolds, tensors, curvature

I have a doubt in the last step of the derivation of the second variation formula for the length functional (Lee's intro to riemannian geometry) (theorem 10.22 see the proof below)

**Why is it true that**

$Rm(\gamma',\gamma',\cdot,\cdot)=Rm(\cdot,\cdot, \gamma',\gamma')=0$**?**

The first one seems to be interchange of 1st and 2nd entry with 3rd and 4th entry, but that doesn;t help me to see that it is 0. Furthermore even knowing this...

**how does that implies that:**

$Rm(V,\gamma',\gamma',V)=Rm(V^\perp,\gamma',\gamma',V^\perp)$ **?**

**I tried using symmetries of the Riemann tensor, but nothing seems to work. Could you show me how is done?**

$Rm(V,\gamma',\gamma',V)=Rm(V^\perp,\gamma',\gamma',V^\perp)$ **?**

$Rm(V,\gamma',\gamma',V)=Rm(V^T+V^\perp,\gamma',\gamma',V^T+V^\perp)=$
$Rm(V^\perp,\gamma',\gamma',V^\perp)+Rm(V^T,\gamma',\gamma',V^T)+Rm(V^T,\gamma',\gamma',V^\perp)+Rm(V^\perp,\gamma',\gamma',V^T)  $

Somehow the last 3 terms should cancel

**As a side thing why is $D_t \gamma'=0?$**

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- You have skew-symmetry in the first two slots, $R_{abcd}=-R_{bacd}$, and also in the last two slots, $R_{abcd}=-R_{abdc}$, hence the $0$.
- Just plug in $V=V^{\top}+V^{\bot}=c\dot{\gamma}+V^{\bot}$ into $R(V,\dot{\gamma},\dot{\gamma},V)$ and use multilinearity. You’ll get a sum of four terms. One of them will be $R(V^{\bot},\dot{\gamma},\dot{\gamma},V^{\bot})$, and the other three will vanish because each of those terms will have $3$ occurrences of $\dot{\gamma}$, so by the skew-symmetry property mentioned above, will vanish.

Another way of saying this is that $R(\dot{\gamma},\dot{\gamma},\cdot,\cdot)=0$ implies by scalar multiplying in the first slot that $R(V^{\top},\dot{\gamma},\cdot,\cdot)=0$. Similarly, $R(\cdot,\cdot,\dot{\gamma},V^{\top})=0$, so the last three terms vanish.

Comment: I see... great thanks, Any idea about the side question?

Comment: @some_math_guy $\gamma$ is assumed to be a geodesic, so $D_t\dot{\gamma}=0$; this is literally what it means to be a geodesic.

Comment: well the definition that I have  is with nabla. If I remember correctly it was $\nabla_ {\dot\gamma}\dot\gamma=0$. I am not use to the $D_t$. I am just taking it as a symbol that appears when taking covariant derivative of an inner product

Comment: @some_math_guy read Lee’s page 101 onwards for how $D_t$ (covariant derivatives along curves) is related to $\nabla$. Anyway, it’s essentially a definition that $D_t\psi$ is denoted $\nabla_{\dot{\gamma}}\psi$.